# A small doubt related to Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

A question is Given that 
$$\sum\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n^p(1+x^{2n})} $$
}
for what value of $\;p\;$ given series of functions is uniformly convergence for all vales of $x\in \mathbb{R}$

**Solution i tried**- The question is simple ,if we apply $M_n-$ test  then we can see that $$\left | \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n^p(1+x^{2n})} \right |\leq \frac{1}{n^p}$$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and also here $\displaystyle M_n=\frac{1}{n^p}$ and $\sum M_n$ is convergent for for $p>1$

**My Question**- As per definition of $M_n$ test they only focus on $[a,b]$ but in this question it is asked on whole $\mathbb{R}$ ,is this legal to use $M_n$ test like i used in above question ,i am confused here because in my book they are using $M_n$ test Dini's test and Drichlit's test over $\mathbb{R}$ but nowhere in the definition of these tests they consider $ \mathbb{R}$.

Please help

Comment: Is the denominator really supposed to be $1+x$? Because then the series isn't defined for $x=-1$. So, as stated, the answer is "for no values of $p$".

Comment: For no  value of $p$ is the series uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$ since it  isi not even defined when $x=-1$.

Comment: apologize, it is my mistake ,i have to edit it

Comment: In that case, you're right, the series converges uniformly on all of $\Bbb{R}$ (because of the Weirstrass $M$ test like you explained).

Comment: but @peek-a-boo my real question is ,is it ok to use this test on whole $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, it is fine to use the test on all of $\Bbb{R}$. For example, take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test Here they only require the functions $f_n$ to be defined on some set $A$. This set $A$ doesn't even have to be a subset of real numbers. It can be literally any non-empty set (in particular it can be all of $\Bbb{R}$).

Comment: Thankyou @peek-a-boo ,these books should use wikipedia's definition

Comment: Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n^p(1+x^{2n})}$. Note that if $p\leq 0$, then $a_n$ doesn't tend to $0$ when $n\to\infty$. If $p>0$, then $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p(1+x^{2n})}$ and the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}$ is convergent . Hence, you need to determine convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p(1+x^{2n})}$.

Comment: My edit was for a typo "Unifrom" in the title.